# WebService dos correios para mais de um produto por frete

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-service

Ola, eu estou usando o webService dos correiros:

http://ws.correios.com.br/calculador/CalcPrecoPrazo.asmx

Para calcular o custo e prazo do frete. A chamada é feita via JS(jquery/ajax) e o webservice esta em C#. Eu já consumo o serviço com sucesso para 1 produto.

A dúvida é: 
E quando existem mais produtos a serem enviados em um único frete? Eu faço o calculo separado e somo? Ou como deve ser feito? Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: O frete não está ligado ao produto em si, mais ao pedido inteiro, o que define esta relação é distância entre a origem e o destino da entrega.

Answer (score 3):

Você pode somar as informações peso altura largura comprimento e fazer a cubagem.
Se não ultrapassar os limites maximos do correio ele vai calcular de boa.
Caso ultrapasse você deve enviar separadamente ou usar uma transportadora.